# Building an active appearence model using the menpo API in python

Tags: python, image-processing, menpo

Is there any good tutorial explaining how can an Active Appearence Model can be implemented using the Menpo API in python ?

I was unable to find one at the menpo website:
http://www.menpo.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I needed to some more research in their website...
For those with the same problem here is a tutorial about AAMs and Menpo

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/menpo/menpo-notebooks/blob/v0.3.0/notebooks/Deformable%20Models/AAMs%20Basics.ipynb

Comment: Hey! I'm on of the maintainers of the project. If you have any problems, please drop us a line on the users list: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/menpo-users